# How to implement IAP via maven or jcenter

Tags: android, maven, in-app-purchase

I want to implement IAP in my application, when I searched Google I came by this tutorial https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html which - And allow me to take it out of my chest - is repulsive ... Downloading an example to extract the *.aidl library, then import it, then create folders and add classes and so forth.

Where's the simplicity of adding import "Bla Bla Bla" in build.gradle?

P.S: I mean no offense, but this is my feedback as a developer regards this approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One item farther down in the left pane is the [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html), which is exactly what you are looking for:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ian, I couldn't find it on the left pane, but I searched Google for the dependency and I found this helpful blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html